# A question about my exam

Tags: arithmetic

Need help for my exam "If a product is sold for 2500 euros, then the loss would be 8%.
How much should the product be sold to reach 8% profit?"

Comment: Is your exam over? If not, it is probably a violation of your school's honor code to ask us for help like this.

Comment: It ended probably about two weeks ago.

Comment: Is it possible to have a title that would reflect the *mathematical* content of the question, instead of its mathematical *context*?

Comment: You might want to mention that next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is sometimes lack of clarity when one deals with percentages: $8\%$ of what?

My interpretation is $8\%$ of the price the item cost us. So let $C$ be that cost.
We have 
$$C-(0.08)C=(1-0.08)C=(0.92)C=2500.$$

To make an $8\%$ profit, we have to sell at price $P$, where 
$$P=C+(0.08)C=(1.08)C$$
Use the first equation to find an expression for $C$, and then use the second equation to find an expression for $P$. Finally, calculate.